# ArrayDeque class of Deque

Tags: java, arrays, collections, deque, java-6

Since ArrayDeque class implements Deque and since it doesn't have any capacity restrictions. 
What is the purpose of Exception throwing methods like `addFirst()`, `addLast()`, etc? It will add the elements in any case since the array has no boundaries. Can someone please explain the with an implementation where we could use within `try{}catch{}` block and a scenario where addFirst could throw an exception?

```
try{ArrayDeque adObj = new ArrayDeque();
adObj.addFirst("Oracle");//we can keep on adding first. Use to exception handling?
}catch(Exception e){
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayDeque` does have potential capacity problems that mean it could throw.  It doubles capacity each time it is expanded so eventually it can't double any more.  One implementation of the code does the following:

```
private void doubleCapacity() {
    int n = elements.length;
    int newCapacity = n << 1;
    if (newCapacity < 0)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Sorry, deque too big");
}
```

With the definition of `addFirst` being as below this method can throw at least two of the exceptions described in the documentation on the interface.

```
public void addFirst(E e) {
    if (e == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    elements[head = (head - 1) & (elements.length - 1)] = e;
    if (head == tail)
        doubleCapacity();
}
```

As others have mentioned the JavaDoc on the interface just gives possible exceptions.  None of the types it throws are checked exceptions so you aren't forced to catch them.

Answer (score 1):

The only exception that [`ArrayDequeue.addFirst()` is documented to throw](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html#addFirst%28E%29) is a `NullPointerException`. Since that is an unchecked exception, you don't need that catch-block.

Answer (score 0):

Some implementations of `Deque` are bound (i.e. limited in capacity), some are not. Methods such as `addFirst` throw an `IllegalStateException` if the limit has been reached. Other methods such as `offerFirst` return a boolean value to indicate the very same result.

If you don't want to handle a potential exception, or know there won't be any, just use `offerFirst` and ignore the result.

Answer (score 0):

A `Deque` throws `IllegalStateException` because Java allows you to use a different or create your own implementation of `Deque`, which may have size restrictions.  `ArrayDeque` does not throw these exceptions, so if you are absolutely certain that your code will use `ArrayDeque` then declare them as such and they will not throw `IllegalStateException`